# Looping through an javascript object literal but start in the middle

Tags: javascript, object

I am looking for a way to loop through an object but starting for example some where in the middle or any other value, for example: Tue, Wen, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun, Mon instead of Sun, Mon, Tue, Wen, Thu, Fri, Sat(as the object used in the example).

// basic week overview

```
daysByName = {
    sunday    : 'Sun', 
    monday    : 'Mon', 
    tuesday   : 'Tue', 
    wednesday : 'Wed', 
    thursday  : 'Thu', 
    friday    : 'Fri', 
    saturday  : 'Sat'
}
```

// basic loop

```
for (var key in daysByName) {
    console.log(daysByName[key]);
}
```

Comment: There is no *order* in which an object is looped through. Therefore there will be no accurate answer to your exact question. You have to choose an implementation, where you store your objects in an array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try something like this, where startIndex is the startIndex you want to start.

```
daysByName = {
    sunday    : 'Sun', 
    monday    : 'Mon', 
    tuesday   : 'Tue', 
    wednesday : 'Wed', 
    thursday  : 'Thu', 
    friday    : 'Fri', 
    saturday  : 'Sat'
}

// Obtain object length
var keys = [];
for (var key in daysByName) {
    keys.push(key)
}

// Define start index
var startIndex = 4, count = 0;
for (var key in daysByName) {
    // Index is made by the count (what you normally do) + the index. Module the max length of the object.
    console.log(daysByName[ keys[ (count + startIndex) % (keys.length)] ]);
    count++; // Don't forget to increase count.
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MH7JJ/2/

Comment: @user759235: Remember to not relying on looping through an object

Comment: This answer is incorrect as object properties don't have an order.

Comment: A function exists to get keys in an array `Object.keys(daysByName)`

Comment: @AlanFoster right, but it's not widely supported yet, and anyway it won't address the order issue.

Comment: Guys, this works correctly in every browser. Why is it wrong?

Comment: @Niels some versions of Chrome and Opera don't follow the order. The specs explicitly state that object properties are unordered. You are correct to expect that in practice it'll work in most cases, but I sincerely doubt that you have tested every browser. The correct practice is to use an array if the order is important to you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rely of the order of properties in an object, and the result might depend on the browser (for example properties reordered alphabetically). And you cannot rely on for...in alone to capture the properties, you need to add an hasOwnProperties() filter.

You have two alternatives:

- use an array instead of an object

  daysByName = [
    {sunday: 'Sun'}, 
    {monday: 'Mon'}, 
    ...
  ]
- enter the index in the object itself:

  Sunday:{abbreviation:"Sun",index:0}